# MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I'm trying to update the fields in the database, but I couldn't

here is my routes :

```
Route::get('orders', [
    'uses' => 'OrderController@postOrder',
    'as'   => 'order.show'
]);
```

here the controller:

```
        public function postOrder()
    {
        $this->orderForm->validate(Input::all());
        $order = $this->orders->getNew([
            'link'       => Input::post('link'),
            'size'       => Input::post('size'),
            'color'       => Input::post('color')
        ]);
        $this->orders->save($order);
        return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Order has been updated');
    }
```

here is the blade:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        {{ Form::label('title', 'Product:') }}
                        {{ Form::text('title', $order->title, ['class' => 'form-control', ]) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('link', 'Link:') }}
                        {{ Form::text('link', $order->link, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('size', 'Size:') }}
                        {{ Form::text('size', $order->size, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            {{ Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

so each time I try to update the order I got error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException ", I tried a lot of methods but I'm lost. I'm still beginner in php and this problem drive me crazy, so I'll be glad if you can help guys.

thanks

*** I've updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added this in the repository:

```
public function updateOrder($id, array $data)
{
    $orders = $this->getById($id);

    if (!empty($data['title'])) {
        $orders->title = $data['title'];
    }

    if (!empty($data['link'])) {
        $orders->link = $data['link'];
    }

  (AND SO ON)

    $orders->save();
```

and in the controller:

```
    public function postOrder($id)
{
    $this->orders->updateOrder($id, Input::all());

    return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Updated');
}
```

and that's it

Answer (score 2):

So you're posting to the route, `/orders`. Therefor you need a `HTTP POST request`. You're now assigning a `GET` request to the `/orders` route.

You need to change your code to:

```
Route::post('orders', [
    'uses' => 'OrderController@postOrder',
    'as'   => 'order.show'
]);
```

Also you need to add a `CSRF Token`, this can be done through adding `{!! csrf_field() !!}` in your blade (inside your Form open and close).

```
{{ Form::open() }}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                    {{ Form::label('title', 'Product:') }}
                    {{ Form::text('title', $order->title, ['class' => 'form-control', ]) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('link', 'Link:') }}
                    {{ Form::text('link', $order->link, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('size', 'Size:') }}
                    {{ Form::text('size', $order->size, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        {{ Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the method in the Form::open method.

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'post')) }}
```

Comment: @Kovah  I've done what you've advised sir, and now I'm getting this error"validation.required", and I think I know how to solve, so I'll give it a try. thanks